# Is there a more elegant hide/show pattern in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

On a crowded screen I have it is is incorporating many  ng-hide/ ng-show directives.

The common pattern to do that is:

```
<div  . . ng-hide="showCurveForm" ng-click="toggleCurveForm()">
                    Show Curve Form
</div>
<div  . . ng-show="showCurveForm" ng-click="toggleCurveForm()">
                    Hide Curve Form
</div>
```

Which is supported in the controller like so:

```
$scope.toggleCurveForm = function () {
   $scope.showCurveForm = !$scope.showCurveForm;
};
```

**Question** Are there patterns that do not require me cluttering my controller with many of these "switches?"

It just seems verbose.  I only want to flip a `Boolean` while still following all the guides that say my controllers should be thin.

Comment: This is really opinion based - there are many many approaches and the "best" one is going to depend on what you are trying to do. That said, have you looked into using templates in separate files? If you combine this concept with multiple controllers you can really clean things up.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the response but I am not sure what you mean "using templates in separate files?"

Comment: I would look into some sort of event delegation but I don't have a solution at this time for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, create your own directive. For example:

```
app.directive('toggleThis', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-hide="showCurveForm" ng-click="toggleCurveForm()">Show Curve Form</div>'+
    '<div ng-show="showCurveForm" ng-click="toggleCurveForm()">Hide Curve Form</div>'
    };
});
```

This way you can strip your HTML down to something like:

`<toggle-this></toggle-this>`

and it will be replaced with your directive template. In addition, this new directive can be used repeatedly throughout your site/app.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq3At/1/) for a working example, using your code above.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your switch right in the click like this:

```
<a href ng-click="showCurveForm = !showCurveForm">Toggle</a>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/LbGD2ybqR9ByWex7CIMk)

Comment: That is cleaner!  I was just hoping for a "toggle-this" directive that I wasnt seeing in the docs. But this works!